# When may we ignore the limits of integration?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

When we try to evaluate an integral such as, say

$$\int_a^b{f(x)dx}$$

there is often the case that we can analytically find

$$\int{f(x)dx}$$

a little faster (imagine leaving away the evaluation for specific terms for partial integrations, if you lack an example. Partially integrating forces you to evaluate two terms instead of one all of the sudden).

Therefore, I feel tempted to leave away the limits of integration in general and evaluating it at the very end, to save some time.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure if this holds for every scenario. Think of integration by substitution, where the limits might change due to substituting.

And so, I want to ask: When exactly can I just ignore the limits of integration and apply them to an indefinite integral instead?

If you're having trouble to understand the difference, just give
$\int_0^{\pi}{e^x\cdot cos(x)dx}$ a try. Finding $\int{e^x\cdot cos(x)dx}$ is easy, but trying to find $\int_0^{\pi}{e^x\cdot cos(x)dx}$ directly (using partial integration and evaluating all the terms mid-way) is somewhat cumbersome.

Comment: To the contrary, the definite integral expressions in your example will be simpler. If we let $u=e^x$ and $dv=\cos x\,dx$ then $uv$ dies at both ends.

Comment: You can always do this---this is the content of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: More precisely, if $F$ is any antiderivative of $f$, then $\int_a^b f(x) \,dx = F(b) - F(a)$, provided that $f$ is well-behaved on the interval $[a, b]$; here, continuity is sufficient for being well-behaved.

In practice people very often do exactly this, though, NB that there are some definite integrals whose values can be evaluated, but for which the corresponding indefinite integrals have no antiderivative in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Could you elaborate on that? I'm not entirely sure if I understood your line of argument.

Comment: In doing the integration, you will do integration by parts twice. The first integration by parts gives $\left.uv\right|_0^{\pi}uv-\int_0^\pi v\,du$. Here $u$ and $v$ are as above. Because $\sin 0=\sin\pi=0$, the first term $\left.uv\right|_0^{\pi}uv$ is $0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I see now, thank you! If anyone wants to write an answer to this question, I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope someone will write an answer. I won't today (it is late here). Roughly speaking when one can find antiderivatives, one can wait to evaluate until the end, though it may be inconvenient. For example, when we do substitution it can save time to substitute for the limits. There are also situations where we cannot find an explicit antiderivative, but can find $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ for certain special choices of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Chiru, you can write up the answer to your own question if you like - there is no objection to this.  Perhaps include a comment giving credit where it is due for the ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I'll try to answer it myself, now that the question has been discussed in the comments. Thanks a lot to Travis and André Nicolas!

In general, we may **always** ignore the limits of integration. This is easily justifiable by the **Fundamental Theorem of Calculus**:

$$\int_a^bf(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(a) = \left[ F(x) \right]_a^b = \left[ \int f(x)\,dx \right]_a^b $$

given that $f$ is well-behaved on $[a, b]$.

Note, though, that there are some definite integrals that we can solve exactly without being able to express their anti-derivatives in terms of elementary functions (thanks, Travis).